# Dropbox won't running on debian

Tags: debian, dropbox

I'm trying to install dropbox on my distro debian jessie i386 but it won't start.

With the command ***dropbox start -i*** the result is ***Dropbox isn't running. Done***

If I start dropboxd (on dropbox-dist folder) the error is ***Segmentation fault***

I tried different version that are listed here:

https://linux.dropbox.com/packages/debian/

But it gives me the same result.

Can anybody tell me what may be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had success after scanning for missing library dependencies of the Dropbox distribution, and installing those that were missing. Basically you can run something like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.8.8/ ldd ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.8.8/* 2>/dev/null|grep "not found"
```

Change the distribution path to match yours. In my case, the shipped libQt5WebKit.so.5 and libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 libraries depended on libxslt.so.1, which is not included in the Dropbox distribution. After installing it on my Debian Jessie system (package "libxslt1.1"), everything was working right away.

Dropbox distribution version: 3.8.8; Debian "dropbox" package (installer) version: 2015.02.12.

I have just now, 2015-Sep-07, requested that the Debian "dropbox" package on linux.dropbox.com/debian/ is changed to depend on the "libxslt1.1" package to fix that particular problem.

Comment: doing a `sudo apt-get install libxslt1.1` worked for me in Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a problem with the .deb from dropbox, did you try compiling it from source?

https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Follow these instructions

> Dropbox Headless Install via command line
>
> The Dropbox daemon works fine on all 32-bit and 64-bit Linux servers.
>   To install, run the following command in your Linux terminal.
>
> 32-bit:
>
> cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" |
>   tar xzf -
>
> 64-bit:
>
> cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" |
>   tar xzf -
>
> Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist
>   folder.
>
> ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
>
> If you're running Dropbox on your server for the first time, you'll be
>   asked to copy and paste a link in a working browser to create a new
>   account or add your server to an existing account. Once you do, your
>   Dropbox folder will be created in your home directory. Download this
>   Python script to control Dropbox from the command line. For easy
>   access, put a symlink to the script anywhere in your PATH.

For more information you can read through [this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=110350)